# Sorting a non-integer 2D numpy array

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

how would you sort a 2d array with x and y coordinates that are non-integers and are approximate? So, for example such an array as:

```
[
[0.005, 0.02]
[-0.1, 1.001]
[0.99, 0.004]
[1.1, 0.995]
]
```

Keep in mind that the [0.005, 0.02] corresponding to the x,y coordinate of [0,0] does not necessarily have the lowest x coordinate or the lowest y coordinate. I have seen how to do it for integers, but I am not sure for this case.

Comment: By sorting, I mean sorting according to both axes

Comment: For sorting you must define a criterium of comparison, such that `X_1 = (x_11, x_12) < X_2=(x_21, x_22)` e.g. if `x_11 < x_21 or (x_11 == x_21 and x_12 < x_22)` or if `||X_1|| < ||X_2||`... In general the built-in function `sorted` does the first variant of my examples for any iterable argument.

Comment: I probably can writ something to do it myself, like looking at the squared distance (x^2 + y^2) for example and continuing from there, but I was more looking at if there is a simple way to do this

Comment: @Tammy, Can you show us your desired output from sorting the NumPy array in your question?

Comment: Or you can do `np.array(sorted([list(a) for a in A]))` if `A` is the vector of cordinates.

Comment: @jpp The example is exactly how I want it, but the rows could have been fed in any random way, so my input could have been:
[
[1.1, 0.995]
[-0.1, 1.001]
[0.005, 0.02]
[0.99, 0.004]
]

Comment: Okay, then again: What is your criterium of comparison? Is it the absolute value (eulerian norm) of each coordinate? Then your example list is not sorted that way... [0.02, 1.006, 0.99, 1.483]

Comment: @SvenKrüger sorry, example of what? The absolute value is a criterium, but not the only one as it would not differentiate between x and y. Basically I want this:
[
[0,0],
[0,1],
[0,2],
...
[1,0],
[1,1],
[1,2],
...
]
and so on, but since the values measured are approximate, and the values for 0,1,2 can be within certain bounds higher or lower, a simple function doesnt do the trick

Comment: Then try the code from my comment above, if it suits your requirements.

Comment: @SvenKrüger sorry, it doesn't as it will start with the x,y coordinate [-0.1, 1.001] which has the lowest x coordinate but is not corresponding to the [0,0] x,y coordinate

Comment: Have you tried rounding the numbers or simply converting them to integers before sorting?

Comment: This is a possible workaround, but the data I am getting can be high in number and I don't know beforehand how approximate they will be, so the error might be larger than 1, with x,y coordinates like [998,501.5] corresponding to [1000,500]. Basically I will be getting x,y coordinates with the x coordinates in roughly the same rows and the y coordinates in roughly the same columns

Comment: If your data is already sorted, why bother?

Comment: This makes no sense! How can one know that approximate 0.005 comes before approximate 0? or that 0.999 should actually come after 1.001 in an "approximately sorted" list. It assumes you know the truth (ideal; correct) value. And if so, just use the truth.

Comment: What is the overall problem that you are working on? It seems like this is a systematic error.

Answer (score 0):

As Sven pointed out, you need a comparison. If you are sorting by distance, then you need to compute at least the square. You can use this:

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[0.1,0.2],[-1,0.5], [2,2], [0,0]])
x[np.multiply(x,x).sum(axis=1).argsort()]
```

If you want to sort by x or y, you can use argsort on a slice:

```
x[x[:,0].argsort()] # sort by x
x[x[:,1].argsort()] # sort by y
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an (N,2) array of floats. I made a dummy array similar to yours:

```
>>import numpy as np
>>A = np.random.random((5,2))*3 - 1 
>>A

array([[-0.09759485,  1.09646624],
       [ 1.24045241,  0.59099876],
       [-0.43080349, -0.33879412],
       [ 0.82403019,  0.16274243],
       [ 1.95623418, -0.64082276]])
```

From what you said, these values are approximate. Before ordering them we can round them to the nearest integers.

```
>>A = np.round(A)
>>A
array([[-0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [-0., -0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 2., -1.]])
```

Now `numpy.sort()` should give you the array ordered how you wanted:

```
>>np.sort(A, axis=0)
>>A
array([[-0., -1.],
       [-0., -0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  1.]])
```

Comment: I guess rounding is the best way to go about, you just have to know the maximum error